Odds of multiple correct 5050 guesses
let me begin by saying I am NOT a mathematician at all. But I've been pondering a mathematical question. I recently watched a gameshow where a contestant was faced with a challenge of correctly guessing the image that the host was looking at on a card. She had one of two choices and the round would continue until she guessed wrongly. She guessed correctly 14 times and I believe the probability of this to be very low. Because with each subsequent correct guess, the odds (in my mind) increase. So the first guess was 1 in 2 but then the second guess was 1 in 4, the third 1 in 6 and so on. Am I correct in my understanding of just wildly misunderstanding probabilities? Thank you!

Actually, the third should be $1$ in $8(=2\times2\times2)$.

If she was just guessing with $50$-$50$ odds for each guess, the odds of $3$ correct in a row are $1$ in $8$, not $1$ in $6$.  Imagine $8$ trials.  She’ll get the first answer right in $4$ of them, the second answer right in $2$ of those $4$, and the third answer right in $1$ of those $2$.  You need to double the size of the “sample space” for each subsequent correct guesss, so her odds of $14$ consecutive correct $50$-$50$ guesses are $1$ in $2^{14}$, or $1$ in $16384$.

Ahhh I see, thank you. I see where I went wrong though I think my reasoning was, in principle, correct. I appreciate the explanations, thank you again :)

This is so unlikely that without more information it sounds like the contest was rigged. Try guessing a coin flip right $14$ times in a row, it's not so easy!

I totally agree with you and is why I started thinking about it because I was and am convinced she was cheating

Very unlikely , yes , but not impossible. If I remember right , the world record for a chain of "reds" in roulette in a casino is $26$ (it could also be $29$ , maybe someone can clarify that). Also, who knows whether she actually guessed ? I hate those quiz shows anyway , in particular if alternatives are given allowing the candidates to guess.
